# How display images that stored in database in spring mvc

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to display hows detail with images. in fact may be one how not have image. here is my controller to display it

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/Hows/{categoryId}/{categoryName}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showHowsCategory(@PathVariable("categoryId")int category,Model  model,HttpServletRequest request){

    int page = 1;
    if(request.getParameter("page")!=null)
        page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page").toString());

     ListHows = showCategoryService.showAllHowInCategory(category,(page- 1)*pageSize,pageSize);
     for(int i=(page-1)*pageSize;i<pageSize;i++){
         byte[] binaryData = ListHows.get(i).getImage();
         if(binaryData != null){
         try {
                byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encode(binaryData);
                String base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8");
                imageList.add(base64Encoded);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
     }
     model.addAttribute("image", imageList);
     model.addAttribute("howList",ListHows);
```

and in jsp view use this code. but not display images.

```
  <c:forEach var="how" items="${howList}" varStatus="counter">
             <c:set var="url" value="${how.how}"/>
              <c:set var="count" value="0"  />
             <div class="table">
            <div style="float: left;margin-left: 10px;">
             <c:if test="${how.image != null}">
                         <img  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${image[count]}"  width="150" height="120"/>
                           <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" />
                      </c:if>
                      <c:if test="${how.image == null}">
                        <img width="150" height="120" src="<c:url value="/resources/images/how.jpg" />"/>
                      </c:if>
                      </div>
```

what is my problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <img  src="data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,${image[count]}"  width="150" height="120"/>
```

data will be the encoded base64 string.

Comment: when i use this   model.addAttribute("image", imageList.get(2)) and in jsp view <img  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${image}"  width="150" height="120"/> its work.

Comment: Yes I understand you situation but you use foreach in another list.
Maybe you need to put image's data into howList. You can refenrence that like this.

 <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${image[counter]}" width="150" height="120"/>

your count is always zero when you start to loop so you always get ${image[0]}

Comment: but increment count by this <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" />. why display for one image> how to put it into howList?